# jQuery DataTable - need to change the label based on the row value in run time

Tags: jquery, datatables

[image]

Below table developed in the jQuery DataTable Need to add label for Status based on the condition if status "0" then "Inactivate" and for "1" - Active.

Comment: If you use AJAX as a data source you'll could preprocess your data before sending it.

Comment: are you using server binding or the ajax binding

Answer (score 2):

Have you investigated `fnRowCallback`?
http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks#fnRowCallback

If you look at the example on the DataTables site, 
and play with the jsbin example, it sure seems to 
be what you're looking for...

Answer (score 0):

```
"render": function (data, type, row) {
                    if (data == "Y") {
                        data = "Approved"
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        data = "Pending"
                    }
                    return data
                },
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).